# Changing the background color of an intellij pane

Tags: java, intellij-idea, color-scheme

I've changed the color scheme in intellij so that the background of the Java editor pane is dark and the text is light.  I'm not sure if this is directly related, however, in other windows such as the 'run' window, the background stays white but any system messages are displayed as white text.  This is obviously a problem as I can't read white text on a white background unless I manually highlight the text to have the background a different color.

Is there a way to change the background color of other panes other than the editor pane in IntelliJ?

Comment: Is there any simple time tested solution hiding in the answers? something like tweaking some settings directly from inside the UI without installing anything new?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

** **Edit** ** As of Intelli-J Idea 12, Dark is the default!  See my points below for versions 10/11

---

There is a way now - install the 'patch-ide' plugin in combination with the 'color-ide' plugin, and you will get your background colors across all the other panes and throughout the preferences of the application.  If you just want to style your project tree also, use 'color-tree'

http://plugins.jetbrains.net/category/index?pr=webide&category_id=25

As a side note, here is an excellent dark color scheme, BlueForest

http://www.decodified.com/misc/2011/06/15/blueforest-a-dark-color-scheme-for-intellij-idea.html

Comment: This works quite well when applying Solarized Dark scheme upon the default Dracula theme. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: the plugin name is Color ide and Color tree without the hyphen

Comment: What about color in the other panes like Structure?

Answer (score 29):

I believe if you restart IntelliJ, it will update the background of all panes (tool windows).

If you are having trouble to revert back to light frames, there is a way to do that.

Locate the your IntelliJ settings folder (on Windows, it is typically `C:\Users\{username}\.IdeaIC12\`, on Mac, it is something like `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea13/options`. Of course you have to select the appropriate IntelliJ folder)).

Go to the folder `config\options\`.

Edit the file `options.xml`.

Delete these lines:

```
    <component name="LafManager">
      <laf class-name="idea.dark.laf.classname" />
    </component>
```

Done.

Comment: +1; this worked for me on IntelliJ 13 . Weird that switching from "Default" to "Darcula" changes the panel backgrounds; but changing from Darcula to default does not.

Comment: Great answer. Don't know why it's not the accepted one. You're welcome to update for mac users, the file is in `~~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea13/options` (update the version in the path to the correct one)

Comment: In IntelliJ 14 this features moved to laf.xml %USERPROFILE%\.IntelliJIdea14\config\options\laf.xml

Comment: For v14 on OS X, this is located in /Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea14/options/laf.xml

Answer (score 10):

How about this way.

```
File->Settings->Editor->Color & Fonts->General->Default text
```

Choose other color

then

Click the "`Apply`" button.

Comment: Doesn't it change the editor color? He wrote that he *already changed* the editor background, but it didn't affect backgrounds of **other panels**, which is what he wants to change.

Answer (score 6):

On Mac Ox and Idea 14 after changing back to Default theme you should also modify
    `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea14/options/laf.xml`
and change
    `<laf class-name="com.intellij.ide.ui.laf.darcula.DarculaLaf" />`
to
    `<laf class-name="com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel" />`

Comment: This worked for me in Idea 14 (deleting the line as proposed in other solutions just made it re-appear with the DarculaLaf value).

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution:

Go to view -> Quick switch Scheme....  and change option 5. Look and feel to Dracula

Answer (score 2):

Here's the latest 2016 that worked for me. I had changed the white background for editors but all the panes were still black. Selecting Quick Switch Scheme -> Look and feel -> default option - solved it for me, i.e. white panes.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/switching-between-schemes.html

Answer (score 2):

For all using intellij IDEA 15

if the problem is inconsistent colors in different panes try this :

View -> Quick Switch Schemes - Look and Feel -> Intellij (Note : not same as default)

Problem might be that you said yes to 'set Dracula theme to be the default' earlier when changing to dracula from white theme.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get everything with a black background + a nice skull wallpaper.

https://github.com/phackwer/DarkKnight_IntelliJ

I usually disable Tool Buttons, Tool Bar and Status Bar on the View Menu and also run the project on Full Screen mode. Looks sensational!

You can change the wallpaper to a different one by pressing shift twice and looking for Set Background Image.

Answer (score 1):

File->Settings->Editor->Color & Fonts->General->Text -> Background in read-only-files

You can customize the background in read-only files which is in this case diff-merge pages

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be a way.  I'll either have to revert my color scheme back to the default, keep the white on white text in the 'run' pane or convince my work to get me a mac so i can use the magic key combination to invert all colors on the screen!

Comment: You can do the same on Windows (http://www.wikihow.com/Invert-Colors-on-Windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

I like to play around with different themes and installed a bunch of them. After a while when I switched back to IntelliJ Light, this happened -

[image]

The **opened files bar** in editor couldn't retrieve its default colors. I tried -

1. Switching between themes (View -> Quick switch scheme -> Theme -> Selecting another one
2. Restart the IDE
3. Finally I did this - **Files -> Settings -> Plugins -> And disabled all installed themes** and restart

And voila!

[image]

Hope this helps someone in a similar situation :)

Answer (score -1):

Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts

Set "Scheme" to "Default".
Helps instantly, without restart