# How to change IntelliJ IDEA Scheme & Pane Theme?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, color-scheme

Posts [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473460/changing-the-background-color-of-an-intellij-pane) describe how to import additional schemes or change the appearance of the navigational menu of the IntelliJ IDEA. However, the software comes with three different scheme and two different theme settings: Default+Dracula & Default+Dracula+Windows and they each can be set independently. I.E., you can have a Default (white/blue) navigational menu (theme) with a Dracula Scheme, but how do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the settings of the software, I found out it's quite simple.

1) To change the appearance, go to: 
File>Settings>Appearance & Behavior>Appearance>select your theme.

2) To change your color-scheme, go to:
View>Quick Switch Scheme>Color Scheme>select your color scheme OR press ctrl+backquote >then select your scheme.

See the below example:[image]